# How to get date format for specific country in my android Date picker?

Tags: android, datepicker, locale, date-format

I want to make an code to get country date format via country name in android Date picker.
I have trying with Locale.getDefault to get current country date format. But i need date format via country name in android. Please help me regarding this task.

Answer (score 0):

Use [android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(Context)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#getDateFormat%28android.content.Context%29)

```
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateFormat(Context);
String dateString = dateFormat.format(Date);
```

Comment: what is this i want to get current country date format in my date picker android. This is not working.

Comment: In this code, you must set "Date", what's the time you want to show.

Comment: In "android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(Context)" this link.
Description of document: Returns a DateFormat object that can format the date in short form (such as 12/31/1999) according to the current locale and the user's date-order preference.

Is not it?